# Ruby - Simple way to escape regex characters

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have an expression like this:

```
 s.gsub! /[\?\/\\]/, ''
```

In fact, the list of forbidden characters is longer than that. Some require escaping, some don't. Is there a way I could just put the characters in some literal structure (`?/\`) and say "remove all these from the string". I'm aware of [Regexp.quote](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-quote) but not sure how to use it in this context.

Comment: This should work: `/#{Regexp.quote('?\/')}/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can interpolate a statement inside a Ruby regular expression, exactly like you do for strings.

```
/#{...}/
```

In your case

```
s.gsub! /[#{Regexp.escape('?/\')}]/, ''
```

Comment: Not quite, `\'` escapes the `'`, either use `\\'` or move the backslash to another position.